# Why does Kafka Streams log value as byte array instead of JSON in an error message?

Tags: java, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I have a Kafka Streams application that is consuming from two topics and internally aggregating, transforming and joining data. One of the aggregation steps is adding an id to an ArrayList of ids. Nturally since there was a lot of data the changelog message became too big and was not sent to the changelog topic with the following exception:

```
[ERROR]  (1-producer) 
org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl   - 
task [2_2] Error sending record (key {"eventId":432897452,"version":1} 
value [<byte array>] timestamp 1521832424795) to topic 
<application-id>-KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000016-changelog due to {}; 
No more records will be sent and no more offsets will be recorded for this task. 
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordTooLargeException: The request included 
a message larger than the max message size the server will accept.
```

In this message the key is a nicely formatted JSON as it should be, but the value is an enormous byte array, instead of JSON. I checked the corresponding changelog topic and the messages that were logged before that are JSON strings. Also I am using Serdes for both the key and value class. Here is how the value class looks:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public class AggregatedUsers {
    private List<UserInformation> users;

    public AggregatedUsers() {
        this.users = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public AggregatedUsers(final List<UserInformation> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    public AggregatedUsers(final AggregatedUsers aggregatedUsers) {
        this.users = new ArrayList<>();
        for (UserInformation user : aggregatedUsers.getUsers()) {
            users.add(new UserInformation(user));
        }
    }

    public List<UserInformation> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        AggregatedUsers that = (AggregatedUsers) o;
        return Objects.equals(users, that.users);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(users);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "AggregatedUsers{" +
                "users=" + users +
                '}';
    }
}
```

And the `UserInformation` class:

```
import java.util.Objects;

public class UserInformation {
    private Long userId;
    private Long categoryId;

    public UserInformation() {
    }

    public UserInformation(Long userId, Long categoryId) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
    }

    public UserInformation(UserInformation userInformation) {
        this.userId = userInformation.getUserId();
        this.categoryId = userInformation.getCategoryId();
    }

    public Long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public Long getCategoryId() {
        return categoryId;
    }

    public void setCategoryId(Long categoryId) {
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        UserInformation that = (UserInformation) o;
        return Objects.equals(userId, that.userId) &&
                Objects.equals(categoryId, that.categoryId);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(userId, categoryId);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UserInformation{" +
                "userId=" + userId +
                ", categoryId=" + categoryId +
                '}';
    }
}
```

My question is why is the key logged as JSON and the value logged as byte array instead of JSON?

Comment: What version are you using? Maybe your are hitting this bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6538

Comment: It looks like this is the case. The version that I am using is 1.0.0.

Comment: KIP-182 was introduces in Kafka 1.0... I think there is not much you can do about it atm -- of course, Kafka is always happy to get contributions -- feel free to pick up the ticket an open an PR for it.